# Is there a solution to Newcomb's problem?

Tags: logic

Imagine there are two boxes, one transparent and the other opaque.  In the transparent box lies a thousand units of money.  My options are to select the contents of the opaque box only or both the transparent and opaque box.  A "predictor" can reliably determine what I shall do before I do it, so if I select the former option, I can expect to obtain a million dollar cheque in the opaque box.  However, if I select both boxes, I shall find nothing in the opaque box and a paltry thousand in the transparent box.

As a rational human being, I would simply take the contents of the opaque box and walk away with a cool million.  Yet, as I walk away, I notice there is a thousand in the transparent box, so why can't I just walk back and take it as well for a cool million plus a thousand?
After all, the predictor already fixed the contents of the boxes before my decision, so what choice I make doesn't matter regarding the contents of each box, so it's best to take both.

In other words, what is the conflict between the principle of dominance and the principle of maximizing expected utility?

Comment: I can never get myself to understand or believe in the predictor. I don't think this paradox makes sense because of that. Clearly others disagree.

Comment: @user4894: then you are rejecting the premise of the question, and presumably don't find it worthwhile to engage the question. If you do engage the question, however, then you should carefully consider what follows from the premises.

Comment: One can argue that it only makes sense to accept the dominance principle as a valid principle of rationality when the players' strategies are causally independent of each other.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap It's worse than my rejecting the premises. I observe that the premises are inconsistent. If a predictor can exist, what does it mean to say the player is "rational?" The implication is that the player has free will. But clearly the existence of a predictor negates that assumption. If a predictor exists, then the player has no choice and his "rationality" is irrelevant. The problem as stated makes no sense.

Comment: @user4894: The premise is that you are (and rational behavior is) *predictable*, not irrational. You make  choices based on whatever mechanism supports your mental process. That process either is (or approximates) one which supports "rational" thought (i.e. the ability to reason effectively about ones circumstances and choose accordingly), or it does not. The existence of a predictor changes nothing about that. But to turn the screw, isn't the virtue of rationality that it ought to lead to consistent, i.e. predictable, results? If the predictor can simulate that, how is this contradictory?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Concerning that screw. 1) There is a contradiction if the predictor can (each time) predict the action resulting from a mixed-strategy. The action resulting from a mixed-strategy is unpredictable by definition. 2) Also, the equilibrium selection problem (e.g., the _Stag Hunt_) is provably unsolvable without further assumptions, so there often is no _single_ rational result, but rather a set of them.

Comment: @Watson: 1) A mixed strategy involves a commitment to take both under some circumstances. In that sense the pertinent feature of your behaviour is captured — the choice of strategy —  even if it cannot predict the outcome of your random number generator. Or are you taking issue with the physical realisability of the predictor, rather than the logical limitations of it? 2) If you grant the premisses of the problem, then a well-informed player has one rational choice. If you suppose that the predictor may vary its "strategy", and decide not to pay off at random, then things are less clear-cut.

Comment: Anyway: it's a logic puzzle. If you insist that the predictor make a factual prediction about your choice as set out in the puzzle, you ought also to assume that any basis whatsoever on which you might make a choice, including apparently random processes, are in fact predictable by the predictor — as set out by the puzzle. If you reject this premise, you are not proposing an answer, you are only rejecting the paradox as not being a question worth entertaining.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap The issue, I think, is that the premises of the problem are inconsistent with the (implicit) 'standard' game-theoretic axioms (e.g., independence between players). You may/must choose how to resolve that. I think this comes down to choosing between evidential or causal decision theory. You may even go quantum. :)

Comment: @Watson: Does that mean the the problem is inconsistent, or just that game theory is not an appropriate tool to analyse the problem? Speaking as a quantum information theorist, I think reaching for quantum is not really suitable; reaching for *closed time-like curves* might be, however. This is all beside the point, however --- the point is that whatever tools you might enjoy using for modelling the real world, or whatever trust issues or epistemological barriers you might think would trip up the player or predictor in the real world, the actual Newcomb problem is pretty simple.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Fair point. However, let me throw some more random (and separate) thoughts at you. 3) What's left of the meaning of the word 'option' then? If there is a shift in the meaning of 'option', what then prevents a shift of meaning in any _other_ word in the premise? 4) Will changing the premise to _two_ transparent boxes change your solution? 5) Consistency vs existence. Are you really sure that there is _at least one_ world model that is consistent with the premises _and_ satisfies whatever might be required of world models in general?

Comment: @Watson: 3) An 'option' is a conceivable course of action, and your 'choice' is a selection of an option to realise, based on the mechanism that drives your mental processes generally. The fact that the predictor knows what you will choose (by hypothesis) does not negate the fact that both are possible courses of action over the ensemble of participants, rational/well-informed and otherwise. 4) No, it won't, by construction. The predictor gives you $1M + $1k iff, should it do so, it can infer that you would only take the $1M, and the inference is accurate by hypothesis.

Comment: @Watson: 5) What do you mean by "whatever might be required of world models in general"? If you require that it allow e.g. irreducibly random phenomena which you may exploit, then the predictor cannot make perfect factual predictions of your behaviour. I'm not discussing that. But allow be to give a logical model for the problem: `P1 ≡ (M v N)`, `P2 ≡ (o v t)`, `P3 ≡ (M⇒t)⇒N`, `P4 ≡ (M⇒o)⇒M`. Do these propositions have a model? Because if M and N represent whether the predictor puts $1M in the opaque box or not, and o and t represent whether I take one box or two, this is Newcomb's problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normal arguments regarding maximising expected utility, presuppose that the distribution of conditions is independent of your strategy.

The counterintuitive (and many would say: counterfactual) element of Newcomb's paradox is that the distribution is said to depend on your strategy. You can understand the game easily enough for two strategies:

1. Suppose the predictor actually has the described power, and you both believe it does and trust that it will provide the $1M if you intend to take the contents of only the one box. Then, if only for selfish reasons, you'd be a fool to plan to take the second box. And after the reveal, it doesn't matter that you could then grab the second box as well: **by hypothesis**, you are in that circumstance because of a prediction, **assumed** accurate, that you won't choose to.
2. If the predictor actually has the described power, but you either don't believe it does or don't trust it to provide the $1M, you will be receptive to taking both boxes. The predictor, knowing this (by hypothesis) and also knowing whether you would choose to take the second box given the opportunity, will leave the opaque box empty if so. It would in effect be producing a self-fulfilling prophecy, but only because it knows enough about your intentions to do so, and because it has for some reason resolved only to give you $1M under specific circumstances.

Your strategy, in the game, would obviously depend on whether you think such a predictor is possible, and honest. If you don't, you should take both boxes; if you do believe in the predictor, you shouldn't.

If you believe in the predictor but get an empty box, that's tough: you were wrong either about it's ability to predict (if you go away empty-handed) or its intent to act in good faith (if you intended to take only one box but take both after re-evaluating your relationship with the predictor). However, *the premise of the puzzle* disallows this contingency. You may not believe that the game can be realised in fact, but the premise of the question is that the predictor is both perfect at prediction and honest. *And in this case, any doubt of the player is a matter only of not knowing, or accepting, that premise.*

If you accept the premise of the question, it's obvious how you ought to act. The only question, then, is whether you accept the premise of the question! If you don't, then it's not that Newcomb's paradox is unsolvable: it's that you refuse to regard it as worthy of serious consideration. And that's bound up with issues of philosophical naturalism (computational complexity in particular), and psychology.